# Can a rotating charged carrying sphere act as a disco ball?

Tags: electromagnetism, classical-mechanics, electromagnetic-radiation

So, basically a resting charge has an electric field, a moving charge has a magnetic field while an accelerating charge emmits a electromagnetic waves.

There is a relation between the frequency of accelerating charging and the wavelength of electromagnetic waves emitted.

So is it possible to place a charge on a sphere and rotate the sphere with just the right angular velocity in order to produce light of visible wavelength, making a disco ball?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, at least to an extent. See here: [Synchrotron radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchrotron_radiation)

There are two limitations that I am aware of:

1. In order to emit visible light, you will have to rotate your sphere rather quick. This will also determine the frequency of the light pulses. For the normal human eyes, this will not blink at all (way too quick to resolve).
2. In contrast with the traditional disco ball, the light will be emitted mostly in the equatorial plane of the sphere.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!!